# Compare two arrays of objects by values that relate to differently-named properties

Tags: php, arrays, object, comparison, array-difference

This is probably really simple, but I cannot seem to get it. I have two arrays of objects `$a` and `$b`. In `$a` I have objects with key `email` and in `$b` I have objects with `user_email` (this cannot be changed as it comes from an API). I want as output a third array `$c` that has all the objects where `email == user_email`. I've tried using `array_udiff` like this:

```
$c = array_udiff($a, $b,
    function ($obj_a, $obj_b) {
        return $obj_a->email - $obj_b->user_email;
    }
);
```

For some reason, $obj_b is not always an object from array `$b` as I would have thought. Is there any clean solution for this?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your input data. What is `$obj_b` when it is _not_ an object? Are `$a` and `$b` always the same length?

Comment: @PatrickQ `$a` and `$b` are not the same length. `$obj_b` is always an object as I understand.

Comment: Your question says "$obj_b is not always an object".  Either it _is_ or it _isn't_. It's hard for us to help you if you aren't clear about exactly what's happening.  Can you provide the result of `var_dump($a);` and `var_dump($b);`?

Comment: @PatrickQ I say that `$obj_b` is not always an object **from array $b**, meaning that it is sometimes an object from array $a. It is always an object though. If I `print_r($obj_b)` on the third line, it is sometimes an object from $a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [array_uintersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php). Also, you should compare your strings with [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) or even better with [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php). Remember that the order in which PHP will pass array elements to the callback is not always the same as the order of arrays.

```
$a = [(object)['email' => 'a'], (object)['email' => 'b'], (object)['email' => 'c']];
$b = [(object)['user_email' => 'c'], (object)['user_email' => 'a'], (object)['user_email' => 'd']];

$comparer = function($obj_a, $obj_b) {
    $email_a = property_exists($obj_a, 'email')
        ? $obj_a->email
        : $obj_a->user_email;

    $email_b = property_exists($obj_b, 'email')
        ? $obj_b->email
        : $obj_b->user_email;

    return strcasecmp($email_a, $email_b);
};

// only objects with email property
$c = array_uintersect($a, $b, $comparer);

// both objects with email and user_email property
$d = array_merge(
    array_uintersect($a, $b, $comparer),
    array_uintersect($b, $a, $comparer)
);
```

Testing with `property_exists` can be changed to testing with `instanceof` if the arguments are concrete classes.

Comment: Getting `Undefined property: stdClass::$user_email` error same as with my solution. Isn't $obj_b supposed to be only an object from array `$b`? If I `print_r` `$obj_b` it gives me an object from array `$a`

Comment: Yeah, I should refine this answer. But do you need objects with `email` property or objects with `user_email` property in the result array or maybe both?

Comment: `email` should be fine.

Comment: Updated the answer. The order in which PHP will pass array elements to the callback is not always the same as the order of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with `usort()` functions, the `array_uintersect()` and `array_udiff()` family of functions do not guarantee that the `$a` and `$b` parameters in the callback signature relate to the first and second input arrays.  In fact, these functions allow for more than 2 input arrays, but the number of parameters in the callback signature do not increase.

To resolve the issue you are encountering, use the null coalescing operator to fallback to the opposing object's property if the first attempted property access fails.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RG44S))

```
$emails = [
    (object) ['email' => 'a'],
    (object) ['email' => 'b'],
    (object) ['email' => 'c']
];
$userEmails = [
    (object) ['user_email' => 'c'],
    (object) ['user_email' => 'a'],
    (object) ['user_email' => 'd']
];

var_export(
    array_udiff(
        $emails,
        $userEmails,
        fn($a, $b) => ($a->email ?? $a->user_email) <=> ($b->email ?? $b->user_email)
    )
);
```

Result:

```
array (
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'email' => 'b',
  ),
)
```